# Trying to choose two different start points on a multicarousel page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to pick two different start points for the slide content.  The `setSlideContent` indicator is set to 17 for the main gallery.  But for the modal that will popup if there is alternate variations of that image will start at 0.  Is there a way to start the slide content at 17 for main gallery carousel, but if it is a modal carousel, have it start at 0?  I'm guessing I need an if/else here.

Would (using the original script) changing the `setSlideContent` to check `if $carouselSelector` contains `.modal` `return setSlideSelector(0)` `else if $carouselSelector` does not contain `.modal` `return setSlideSelector(17)` or whatever number I need work? Still extremely new to this.

NOTE in the example below the `setSlideContent` is set to 0 but but it is never set to 0 in practice (unless the carousel is in a modal) to take into account new slides being added.  The number will always be the last slide added in my case it is 17.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.carousel-container').each(function() {
    var $carouselContainer = $(this);
    var $carousel = $carouselContainer.find('.carousel');
    var $carouselText = $carouselContainer.find('.carousel-text');
    var $carouselSelector = $carouselContainer.find('.carousel-selector');

    $carousel.carousel({
      interval: false
    });

    function setSlideContent(id) {
      var targetContent = $carouselContainer.find('.slide-content[data-slide="' +
        id +
        '"]').html();

      $carouselText.html(targetContent);
    }

    setSlideContent(0);

    $carouselSelector.on('click', function() {
      var targetSlide = $(this).data('slide');

      $carousel.carousel(targetSlide);
    });

    $carousel.on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
      var targetSlide = $carousel.find('.active').index();

      setSlideContent(targetSlide);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container carousel-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-0">
        <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="active carousel-item" data-slide-number="0">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=one">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item" data-slide-number="1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=two">
          </div>
          <!-- Carousel nav -->
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-0" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-0" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col carousel-text"></div>
    <div style="display: none;">
      <!-- only needs the inline CSS -->
      <div class="slide-content" data-slide="0">
        <h5>Slide 1</h5>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" type="button" style="margin-left: -1px;">press me</button>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Download</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Downloads/avarice/avarice1/avarice-nodof1280.jpg" download>1280x1024</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-content" data-slide="1">
        <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
        <h5>Slide 2</h5>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Downloads</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Downloads/avarice/avarice0/avarice01280.jpg" download>1280x1024</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <!--/Slider-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <a class="carousel-selector" data-slide="0"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one" class="img-thumbnail"></a>
      <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a class="carousel-selector" data-slide="1"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two" class="img-thumbnail"></a>
      <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container carousel-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-1">
        <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="active carousel-item" data-slide-number="0">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=one">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item" data-slide-number="1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=two">
          </div>
          <!-- Carousel nav -->
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col carousel-text"></div>
    <!-- change this id and match with that in JS -->
    <div style="display: none;">
      <!-- only needs the inline CSS -->
      <div class="slide-content" data-slide="0">
        <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
        <h5>Dreams of Avarice1</h5>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Download</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Downloads/avarice/avarice1/avarice-nodof1280.jpg" download>1280x1024</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-content" data-slide="1">
        <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
        <h5>Avarice Zero1</h5>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Downloads</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Downloads/avarice/avarice0/avarice01280.jpg" download>1280x1024</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <!--/Slider-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <a class="carousel-selector" data-slide="0"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one" class="img-thumbnail"></a>
      <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a class="carousel-selector" data-slide="1"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two" class="img-thumbnail"></a>
      <!-- change this id and match with that in the JS -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>...</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid carousel-container">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row mx-auto">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" id="carousel-...">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active carousel-item" data-slide-number="0">
                      <img data-src="./Downloads/hoohum" src="./loader-carousel.gif" class="lazy img-thumbnail" width="450" height="250"></div>
                    <div class="carousel-item" data-slide-number="1">
                      <img data-src="./Downloads/hoohum" src="./loader-carousel.gif" class="lazy img-thumbnail" width="450" height="250"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row mx-auto">
              <div class="col carousel-text"></div>
              <div style="display: none;">
                <div class="slide-content" data-slide="0">
                  <h5>0ne</h5>
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Desktop</button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Downloads/something/something" download>1280x1024</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dual</button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Downloads/something/something" download>2560x1024 (Dual)</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Triple</button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Downloads/something/something" download>3840x1024 (Triple)</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-content" data-slide="1">
                  <h5>two</h5>
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Desktop</button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Downloads/other/other" download>1280x1024</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dual</button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Downloads/other/other" download>2560x1024 (Dual)</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Triple</button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Downloads/other/other" download>3840x1024 (Triple)</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <!--/Slider-->
          <div class="row mx-auto">
            <div class="col">
              <a class="carousel-selector" data-slide="0"><img data-src="./Downloads/hoohum" src="./loader-thumb.gif" class="lazy img-thumbnail" width="75" height="42"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <a class="carousel-selector" data-slide="1"><img data-src="./Downloads/hoohum" src="./loader-thumb.gif" class="lazy img-thumbnail" width="75" height="42"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add your HTML.

Comment: "I'm guessing I need an if/else here" - yes, or a ternary eg. `setSlideContent((some_condition) ? 17 : 0);`.

Can't help you with the condition as that would require knowledge of the HTML/DOM tree.

Comment: here is a codepen of the multicarousel.  I am using bootstrap 4 beta so keep that in mind when figuring out classes as those have changed from <v4.

https://codepen.io/kyledrew/pen/WZrNQw

Comment: updated html to represent exactly what i'm doing

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?  I updated the question with a thought but I'm unsure as to how to write it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want :

- to initialize the modal carousel at its first slide, with corresponding caption.
- to initialize all other carousels at their last slide,  with corresponding caption.

At least, that would makes sense.

If I'm right, then the javascript will be something like this :

```
$(function() {
    $('.carousel-container').each(function() {
        var $carouselContainer = $(this);
        var $carousel = $carouselContainer.find('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
            var targetSlide = $carousel.find('.active').index();
            var targetContent = $carouselContainer.find('.slide-content[data-slide="' + targetSlide + '"]').html();
            $carouselContainer.find('.carousel-text').html(targetContent);
        }).carousel({
            interval: false
        });
        $carouselContainer.find('.carousel-selector').on('click', function() {
            var targetSlide = $(this).data('slide');
            $carousel.carousel(targetSlide);
        });
        // The carousel is already at first slide (slide 0).
        var n = $carouselContainer.find(".slide-content").length; // number of slides in this carousel
        if (n < 2 || $carouselContainer.closest(".modal").length > 0) { // if there are less than 2 slides, or the carousel is in a .modal container 
            // Trigger the 'slid.bs.carousel' event so its handler can look after the .carousel-text ...
            $carousel.trigger('slid.bs.carousel');
        } else { // ... else, there are 2 or more slides and this is a non-modal carousel: 
            // send to last slide
            $carousel.carousel(n - 1);
            $carousel.trigger('slid.bs.carousel'); // shouldn't be necessary but has been found to be a workaround for `slid.bs.carousel` not being triggered automatically under some (undiagnosed) circumstances.
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zksyLnbn/)**

Comment: Hmm, While the carousels are initializing which wasn't a problem with the previous script. The carousel for the modals is where I start running into an issue.  The first info slide never shows up on initializing and must click on the second slide within the carousel to start showing them.  Running into the same issue with your script.

Out of curiosity, why did you choose .closest?  I'm curious on your thoughts behind that.

Comment: Coudln't edit my other comment but:  The first slide on the main carousel doesn't show up either now using your script.  Possible the two issues are linked?

Comment: As I said, be prepared to do some debugging. `.closest()` is like `.parents()` but more efficient when searching for just one ancestor element.

Comment: Maybe just treat my answer as something to raid for ideas.

Comment: Work on the non-modals first. Take a look at the calculation of `initialSlideIndex`. I probably got the jq selector wrong. It is supposed to count the number of thumbnails.

Comment: The carousel in modal may need initialising when it first becomes visible - ie when the modal is first opened.

Comment: Yeah, was playing around with it.  When I put in 0 after length, the carousel changes from the active image on load to the slide that is in the 0 position (ie oldest image) and the info slide is accurate when it does that.  Unfort that is not what I need to happen.  Number of thumbnails I dont think is the way to go.  The original jquery only had issues when trying to operate a carousel that had two different starting slide points.   I think It needs something like `If(.carousel-container .modal) setSlideContent(0) else(.carousel-container) setSlideContent (17)`  - hope you get the gen idea

Comment: Yes but as I understand it, you need to calculate the `17` value? BTW, `jQuery.contains()` will be useful for the modal/non-modal test.

Comment: Just made a couple of mods to the code. Try it again.

Comment: Nope...same issue as before...neither carousels initialize with the active slides info.

Comment: Then I give up. It's all down to you from here.

Comment: Trying to see if using the original script and changing the `setSlideContent` to check if the `$carouselSelector` contains `.modal` `return setSlideSelector(0)` else if `$carouselSelector` does not contain `modal` `return setSlideSelector(17)` or whatever number I need.  Having trouble writing it though.  Still extremely new to this.

Comment: Yup, there are still issues.

Comment: figured out the issue.   You forgot `$carousel.trigger('slid.bs.carousel');` after the else statement.  If you want to add that then resubmit as an answer.  I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: I can't see why another `$carousel.trigger('slid.bs.carousel');` should be necessary. `$carousel.carousel(n - 1)` should trigger the `slid` event on completion of the slide. It certainly does in my fiddle.

Comment: I honestly am not sure why it needed another after the else statement.  It would not work correctly without it.  Possible another piece of javascript from a plugin was interfering with it, or because of the limited number of slides you were working with, it was working.  I'm usually dealing with over 100 slides so that may be the case.  I'm just thanking I was able to get it working with your help and glad you didn't give up.  I was tearing my hair out (if i had any).  I do have a jquery.lazy plugin applied to keep the modals from loading tll called.  Could be the issue?

Comment: That's possible I guess. Hard to say. Certainly would be nice to know why the `slid` handler doesn't fire automatically. Still, if your workaround works, best thing to do is stick with it.

Comment: BTW if you need a specific slide for some reason (i'm lazy loading images on the carousel) you can change the `n - 1` to `n = 123 //last slide number`